# Delete all the keys except one, but keep all the values in python dictonary

Tags: python, oracle

I need to create a dictionary where I am able to split all the select attributes, from table, where condition into different list, but it should have just 1 key. So far I have tried the below-

```
import pandas
import re
import sqlparse


query = "(select t1.id, t1.feed_id, t2.eff_dt, name, type from table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON ( t1.eff_dt = t2.eff_dt WHERE t2.eff_dt = CAST ( ('2020/12/20') AS DATE) and (t2.name = 'abc' or t2.name='pqr'))"
query2= "SELECT DISTINCT id, feed_id, eff_date FROM"
newInput= input('enter the eff_dt:')
new_where = '("'+newInput+'")'
query1= re.sub("(?<=WHERE t2.eff_dt = CAST \( )(.*)(?= AS DATE)", new_where , query, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
formatted_query = sqlparse.format(query1, reindent=True, keyword_case='lower')
formatted_query1 = sqlparse.format(query2, reindent=True, keyword_case='lower')

a = formatted_query.strip()
a1 = formatted_query1.strip()
newformat = a1+a
newformat.lstrip()
dict_list = newformat.split('\n')

dictOfWords = { i : dict_list[i] for i in range(0, len(dict_list) ) }

newDict = dict(zip(dictOfWords.keys(), [v.strip() if isinstance(v,str) else v for v in dictOfWords.values()]))
newDict
```

This takes the input from user for date and gives the output as below-

```
enter the eff_dt:2022/01/20
{0: 'select distinct id,',
 1: 'feed_id,',
 2: 'eff_date',
 3: 'from(',
 4: 'select t1.id,',
 5: 't1.feed_id,',
 6: 't2.eff_dt,',
 7: 'name,',
 8: 'type',
 9: 'from table1 t1',
 10: 'inner join table2 t2 on (t1.eff_dt = t2.eff_dt',
 11: 'where t2.eff_dt = cast (("2022/01/20") as DATE)',
 12: "and (t2.name = 'abc'",
 13: "or t2.name='pqr'))"}
```

But I need the output as below-

```
{0: 'select distinct id,','feed_id,','eff_date','from(','select t1.id,','t1.feed_id,','t2.eff_dt,','name,','type','from table1 t1','inner join table2 t2 on (t1.eff_dt = t2.eff_dt','where t2.eff_dt = cast (("2022/01/20") as DATE)',"and (t2.name = 'abc'","or t2.name='pqr'))"}
```

Is there a way to do it? Remove all the keys except 1, but keep all the values in the dictionary. I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: your expected dictionary is not valid. what is your expected result?

Comment: @LiorCohen combining all the values but there should be only 1 key

Comment: Unless the statement text is unique, and you have also sanitized all user data, then you should use bind variables.  These will aid scalability for repeated statements, and help protect against SQL Injection attacks.,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's make a new dictionary.

This keeps the `first key` of the original dictionary as the only key and adds all the values as a list to that key.

```
# let d be the original dictionary
k,v = list(d.keys()), list(d.values())
new = {k[0]:v}
print(new)
```

---

I have updated your code directly, let me know if you still face errors.

```
import pandas
import re
import sqlparse


query = "(select t1.id, t1.feed_id, t2.eff_dt, name, type from table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON ( t1.eff_dt = t2.eff_dt WHERE t2.eff_dt = CAST ( ('2020/12/20') AS DATE) and (t2.name = 'abc' or t2.name='pqr'))"
query2= "SELECT DISTINCT id, feed_id, eff_date FROM"
newInput= input('enter the eff_dt:')
new_where = '("'+newInput+'")'
query1= re.sub("(?<=WHERE t2.eff_dt = CAST \( )(.*)(?= AS DATE)", new_where , query, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
formatted_query = sqlparse.format(query1, reindent=True, keyword_case='lower')
formatted_query1 = sqlparse.format(query2, reindent=True, keyword_case='lower')

a = formatted_query.strip()
a1 = formatted_query1.strip()
newformat = a1+a
newformat.lstrip()
dict_list = newformat.split('\n')

dictOfWords = { i : dict_list[i] for i in range(0, len(dict_list) ) }

newDict = dict(zip(dictOfWords.keys(), [v.strip() if isinstance(v,str) else v for v in dictOfWords.values()]))
k,v = list(newDict.keys()), list(newDict.values())
new = {k[0]:v}
new
```

```
{0: ['select distinct id,',
  'feed_id,',
  'eff_date',
  'from(',
  'select t1.id,',
  't1.feed_id,',
  't2.eff_dt,',
  'name,',
  'type',
  'from table1 t1',
  'inner join table2 t2 on (t1.eff_dt = t2.eff_dt',
  'where t2.eff_dt = cast (("2022/01/20") as DATE)',
  "and (t2.name = 'abc'",
  "or t2.name='pqr'))"]}
```

Comment: it gives below error-

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-aab5e26f081e> in <module>()
----> 1 k,v = list(newDict.keys()), list(newDict.values())
      2 new = {k[0]:v}
      3 new

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: Its working fine for me. I have added the dictionary d. which you show as your input. Please check if thats what you are providing it exactly.

Comment: it gives error -

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-6eddf58d5d54> in <module>()
      1 k,v = (d.keys()), (d.values())
----> 2 new = {k[0]:v}
      3 print(new)

TypeError: 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing

Comment: You are making some mistake in copying. I have updated your original code. and it works perfectly fine by me.

Comment: Copy the complete thing and run. let me know if it works

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked. Somehow it was not working in the same notebook. It worked on newly created notebook. Thanks

Comment: Might be some issue with the kernel. Always a good practice to turn off and turn on a device when you see a weird behavior :)

Answer (score 1):

```
a = {0:'zero', 1: 'one', 2: 'two'}
res = {0: list(a.values())}
print(res)  # --> {0: ['zero', 'one', 'two']}
```

Comment: thanks, but I am getting the error str object is not callable.